# ExtJS5: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'idProperty' of undefined

Tags: extjs5

I upgraded from Ext JS 4.2.3 to 5.0.1 and I have the following error. Any ideas?

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'idProperty' of undefinedext-all-debug.js:68239 Ext.define.applyRootext-all-debug.js:6842 setterext-all-debug.js:121857 Ext.define.initComponentext-all-debug.js:36830 Ext.define.constructorext-all-debug.js:8144 Ext.Base.Base.addMembers.callParent`

Comment: Do you have any classes which extends `Ext.data.TreeStore`?

Comment: yes i have.whats the problem with this?

Comment: This exception comes from `Ext.data.TreeStore`, so there might be issue. Please paste this code into your question.